# The object of type Text has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game that has a main play scene and a game over scene. The Game over scene has a button that simply starts the main scene again.

Everything works fine for the first play, but when restarting through the game over screen and trying to add to my score I get the following error:

```
The object of type Text has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
```

I'm not sure why this is, I've tried logging out the referenced text object in the update and it looks fine.

I'm setting the `highScore` by dragging the text UI component to the script in the editor. I've also tried using `GetComponent` but run into the same issue.

Heres the relevant script:

```
public class ScoreHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Text highScore;
  private int score = 0;

  private int basicEnemyValue = 10;
  private int speedyEnemnyValue = 15;
  private int bossEnemyValue = 50;
  private int startingHighScore;

  public static event Action<int> OnScoreChange;

  void OnEnable() {
    BasicEnemy.OnBasicEnemyDestroyed += BasicEnemyDestroyed;
    TankEnemy.OnTankEnemyDestroyed += TankEnemyDestroyed;
    SpeedyEnemy.OnSpeedyEnemyDestroyed += SpeedyEnemyDestroyed;
  }


  void onDisable() {
    BasicEnemy.OnBasicEnemyDestroyed -= BasicEnemyDestroyed;
    TankEnemy.OnTankEnemyDestroyed -= TankEnemyDestroyed;
    SpeedyEnemy.OnSpeedyEnemyDestroyed -= SpeedyEnemyDestroyed;
  }

  void Start () {
    startingHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("highscore", 0);
    highScore.text = "Score: " + score;
  }


  void Update () {
    Debug.Log(highScore); // Looks good here, has a ref to the correct component UnityEngine.Ui.Text
    Debug.Log(highScore.text); // Same as above - has what's set in start
  }

  private void checkHighScore(int score) {
    if (score > startingHighScore) {
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highscore", score);
    }
  }

 // ***HERE IS THE PROBLEM FUNCTION***
  private void updateScoreText() {
    Debug.Log(highScore); // null


    highScore.text = "Score: " + score;
    checkHighScore(score);
    OnScoreChange?.Invoke(score);
  }

  private void BasicEnemyDestroyed() {
    score += basicEnemyValue;
    updateScoreText();
  }

  private void TankEnemyDestroyed() {
    score += bossEnemyValue;
    updateScoreText();
  }

  private void SpeedyEnemyDestroyed() {
    score += speedyEnemnyValue;
    updateScoreText();
  }

}
```

I'm a bit confused as everything looks fine in the update, but seems to loose the component when I call the function on it. I've tried to add dontDestoryOnLoad() to the UI, but that adds a number of other issues with other UI components not being defined.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to avoid using `event` and delegate handlers because unless you are careful can lead to memory leaks and in the case of Unity being careful _where_ to use such things.  The result can lead to issues that you are experiencing now

Comment: @MickyD That makes sense as this is my first time using events and I may have done something wrong. This might be better off as a separate question, but is there a better way to handle events like this in Unity? The above events are fired when enemies are destroyed, and I was trying to keep the enemy code decoupled from the scoring logic.

Comment: There's probably a few ways but maybe define an `interface` that your `ScoreHandler` implements, say `ISupportBasicEnemyProcessing` with a method like `ProcessBasicEnemyDestroyed(IBasicEnemy basicEnemy)` that instances of your `BasicEnemy` invoke.  It's decoupled and abstract via the use of `interface`s.  When creating an enemy pass in an instance to the `ScoreHandler` but the type is `ISupportBasicEnemyProcessing`.  In this way all the enemy knows is that something wants to process stuff (whether that is score processing is incidental)

Answer (score 0):

onDisable -> OnDisable

It's case-sensitve, so your event handlers are never removed.

---

FYI there is a shortcut to insert these messages in Visual Studio: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>